# Showing an Null Reference Exception that values are garbage collected while loading the data

Tags: ios, xamarin

My application is throwing an exception while loading the data and it's showing a message that "requested operation is cancelled due to object is garbage collected".
sometimes My application is working fine but unexpectedly in the middle it,s throwing this exception.

Can any one guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The actual error is a null reference error. The *debugger* is failing due to garbage collection. See 'message' in your screenshot.

Comment: Thank You Rob for your reply ,
I understood that  exception is due to garbage collection ,but can't understand why it is happening.

Comment: No, the exception is NOT due to garbage collection. You can't READ the error message because of the garbage collection, this has nothing to do with your app. I'd say use Xcode to debug your app.

Comment: How can I check the code in Xcode  as I am using Xamarin? @Pochi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this once https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18910/navigation-popasync-not-freeing-page

I don't think it will work or not but please check your xaml file once the issue in the design.If you are manually adding any controls like buttons,labels with bindings (any controls) from your ViewModel or any file it should throw this type exception I also faced this.In my case below line of code worked for me

```
await Task.Delay(your seconds);
```

before or after adding controls

Comment: Thank You Mounika, There is a binding  issue in xaml by using 

await Task.Delay(your seconds); I resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you create some background task in your app and run and in this task, you get the null object.

In this case, you will need to:

put a debugger on System.NullReferenceException and find the exact issue location. please look below image.

[image]

Comment: Thank You @ZiyadGodil . I had tried it but it's not hitting the breakpoint

Comment: This error does have some in common with serialization. please share some more detail to identify this issue.